# play Html5 video and audio simultaneously on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile, web

having headaches with this.. 
I spent several hours searching for solutions a little bit everywhere.
My goal is to launch/play a video and a separated audio on iOS by calling a function that triggers both, whether is through a onclick or mousedown listener.
for example something like:

html:

```
<html>
<video id="videoElement" src="video/video.mp4"></video>
<audio id="AudioElement">
<source id="sfile" src="file.mp3">
</audio>
<div id="btDiv"> play</div>
</html>
```

js:

```
var mybt = document.getElementById('btDiv');
var myVideo = document.getElementById("videoElement");
var myAudio = document.getElementById('AudioElement')              
mybt.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){ myVideo.play();myAudio.play(); }, false);
```

Is that possible ?

Moreover... is it possible to play a video on iOS using a different button instead of it's default UI player button?

thanks :)

Comment: I'm also having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for HTML 5

```
 NSString *embedHTML = @"\
        <html><head>\
        <style type=\"text/css\">\
        body {\
        background-color: transparent;\
        color: white;\
        }\
        </style>\
        <script>\
        function load(){document.getElementById(\"yt\").play();}\
        </script>\
        </head><body onload=\"load()\"style=\"margin:0\">\
        <video id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" \
        width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" poster=\"%@\" autoplay controls></video>\
        </body></html>";


        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,@"http://www.youtube.com/v/HGd9qAfpZio&hl=en_US&fs=1&", self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height,@""];


 [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: This has been super frustrating for me. so you're suggesting me to implement objective-C? how should i integrate it to a html page structure ?

Comment: You can simply take a web view in your vie controller and then put this code to work that video in yopur web view within your app .

Comment: thanks Saurav, I'm not dealing with a App. it's a mobile web page.